# Karma - test function with no return and which sets no scope variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-jasmine

I've been reading up on karma mainly and jasmine a little and have begun to implement testing on my app.

I have the following function :

```
$scope.popup1 = function (isinData) {
    var popup1 = window.open("views/Box_Ladder.html", "_blank",
                        "height = 400, width = 700");
    shareDataService.setIsinClickValue(isinData);
}
```

How on earth do I test this using karma?  The expected result is a popup window opening and the relevant data being passed to my service.  How do I `expect` this?

Answer (score 1):

You spy on `window.open` and expect it to be called with the right arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Even if the function doesn't return something, it should at the minimum cause some side-effect. You need to test the side-effects.

To do this, create and inject a mock object + object method. An example would be as follows:

```
var window = {
    open: function(url, target, specs) {
        var spec, specKey;
        this.href = url;
        this.target = target;
        // Parse through the spec string to grab the parameters you passed through
        var specArray = specs.split(',');
        for (specKey in specArray) {
            spec = specArray[specKey].split('=');
            this[String.trim(spec[0])] = String.trim(spec[1]);
        }
     }
 };
```

Now you can `expect(window.href).toEqual(url)`, `expect(window.target).toEqual(target)`, `expect(window.height).toEqual(400)`, etc.

Additionally, you need to see if `sharedDataService.setIsinClickValue` was invoked. If you cannot access this service within your test, you're going to have to create another mock object + method.

Comment: Ah, things are becoming a little clearer.  Thanks for the input I'm back to the drawing board here but will return.

Comment: Just a quick warning: make sure you're clear when using mock objects in your tests. If done improperly (or if the object being mocked itself changes), it's possible to create a test that passes, even though the code itself is / has become erroneous.